# How to check status of dblink connection in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
do 
    $$
    declare
    val int;
    v_con_count int;
    return_val character varying(2000);
    begin 
    val = 1;
    return_val = 'null'; 
    SELECT count(1) INTO v_con_count FROM dblink_get_connections() 
     WHERE dblink_get_connections@>'{myconn}';
     IF v_con_count = 0 THEN
            PERFORM dblink_connect('myconn', 'loopback_dblink');
     END IF;
    PERFORM dblink_exec('myconn','Begin; insert into PROD.AA values(2);');
    raise notice'return_val %',return_val;
    end $$;
```

I'm trying to insert value into particular table , but it is not inserted although the DBlink connection's status is ON. How to use insert , update, delete statements in DBlink and even how to check the status of DBlink connection in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `COMMIT` to match the `BEGIN`. In that case the transaction will not complete.